# inline SVG works in HTML4 if it's inserted to the document in the runtime?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I'm trying to inline SVG in a HTML4 doc. I was suggested that there might be some problem since HTML4 does not support inline SVG, so I should do it in XHTML instead.

Interestingly, although supporting inline SVG is not part of HTML4 standard, browsers using WebKit should be happy with inline SVG because its parser is capable of parsing HTML5, which duly supports inline SVG. Unfortunately, Firefox is not in the same league.

However, it'll be fine for FF as well if I use JavaScript to append a SVG node to a  container in the runtime(see below. I got this idea from **jquery svg**, a plug-in for jquery). **Why is it ok to do so?** It just seems to me too good to be true. 
(I'm a complete novice in JavaScript programming and probably missing something very obvious......)

```
function onloadSVG(div_container) {
    var svgE = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',
        'svg');
    svgE.setAttribute('version', '1.1');
    svgE.setAttribute('width', div_container.clientWidth);
    svgE.setAttribute('height', div_container.clientHeight);
    div_container.appendChild(svgE);

    var node = svgE.ownerDocument.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',
        'circle');
    node.setAttribute('cx', '100');
    node.setAttribute('cy', '100');
    node.setAttribute('r', '50');
    node.setAttribute('fill', 'red');
    node.setAttribute('stroke', 'black');
    node.setAttribute('stroke-width', '5');
    svgE.appendChild(node);
}
```

Comment: May I ask: why not just put [SVG in XHTML](http://phrogz.net/svg/svg_in_xhtml5.xhtml)? It works correctly in all SVG-supporting browsers, and no JS hacks are needed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I couldn't do that. I'm developing a libary for an experimental language. So far it generates HTML only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of reasons:

#### HTML4 and DOM are not exactly the same thing.

HTML is just a way of saying what DOM nodes need to be created, but DOM can do much more than that. It's like unzipping files to a filesystem. Your filesystem can support symlinks, hardlinks, fifos, permissions and all the fancy stuff that ZIP can't.

Even without SVG you can create DOM that has no HTML syntax. You can nest `<optgroup>`, put `<ol>` in `<p>`, insert text into `<br></br>`, etc.

#### Browsers (with exception of IE) have just one engine

It takes extra effort to disable things that browsers support, but weren't required back when some spec was written. Browsers will support CSS and `<table>` when given HTML 3.2. They will support `<font>` even in HTML4 Strict.

Browsers only special-case some behaviors of quirks mode and `application/xhtml+xml` mode, which are minimum required for compatibility/conformance. Since *lack* of support SVG in HTML DOM is not required for compatibility nor conformance, there's no point spending time on disabling it.

Answer (score 1):

Educated guess: it works because browsers are used to 99% of the web doing things wrong.

Namespaces are part of XML/XHTML, not HTML; the `createElementNS` method makes no sense to use there. However, rather than having some stickler internal mode that freaks when you try to create a namespace element on an HTML document, instead it goes with the flow.

As to whether it even differentiates the document types internally, I don't know. But just like you can create wholly invalid documents with totally broken markup and the browser does its best to honor your intentions (unless you're serving XHTML as `application/xhtml+xml`), so it's doing its level best for you here.